# Can arrays store multiple values in a single index in C?

Tags: arrays, c

I have an assignment that requires us to read a CSV file, and store each row of data in a single index in a `double` array. However, unless I'm mistaken, it's not possible to store multiple values in a single index in an array in C. Instead, I would have to use a `struct` for that.

Can anyone confirm if it is possible store multiple values in a single index in an array in C?

Here is the input CSV file:

```
1.5,-1.5,3
-1,1.5,3
1,-1,7
1,1,3
-1.5,-1.5,3
-1,0.5,3
0.5,0.5,3
-1,-1,8
-3,1,8
-1.7,1,8
1.8,1,0
```

eg. for the first line, can I store `1.5` and `-1.5` and `3` in `array[0]`?

Comment: My question is it possible store multiple values in a single index in an array in C?

Comment: eg. for the first line, can I store 1.5 and -1.5 and 3 in array[0]?

Comment: Have you read about structs yet? An array can consist of single values, structs or of another arrays. Does the assignment really ask for type `double` or might is also be `struct {double a; double b; double c;} array[10];`

Comment: For your example, I want to store 16,73 and 42 as 3 separate values in array[0]? Is this possible?

Comment: Can anyone show me code on how would I store the first line in the CSV file as 3 separate values in a single index in an array?

Comment: I know how to do this with structs.

Comment: `double values[4][2] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}};` the element `values[1]` has two values, namely `values[1][0] == 3.0` and `values[1][1] == 4.0`

Answer (score 1):

You’ll want to use a 2-dimensional array:

```
#define ROWS 9
#define COLS 3
...
double data[ROWS][COLS];
```

and read each row as

```
if ( fscanf( input, "%lf,%lf,%lf", &data[i][0], &data[i][1], &data[i][2] ) != 3 )
{
  // error during input, handle as appropriate
}
```

Thus, each `data[i]` is itself a 3-element array of `double`.